# writing Django custom model field

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to write a custom field that shows size of an item. like:
"small", "medium", "large", "extra large". It have to be optional like IntegerField.
[this is what I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsUIG.png).
I don't know where and what should I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to define a custom Django model field for that. In fact Django already can handle that. You can provide a [**`choices=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) for that:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    SIZE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'small'),
        (2, 'medium'),
        (3, 'large'),
        (4, 'extra large'),
    )
    size = models.IntegerField(choices=SIZE_CHOICES)
```

In a `ModelForm` you can then use a [**`RadioSelect`** widget [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect) to select out of the choices:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('size',)
        widgets = {
            'size': forms.RadioSelect
        }
```